# Proving positive recurrence for a finite state space DTMC

Tags: markov-process, combinatorics, discrete-time

Let $$P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.3 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 \\
0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 \\
0.1 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0.8 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
be the transition matrix for states $S = \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$

I want to figure out which states are positive recurrent. There are some easy cases like for $c$, but I am having a hard time showing that $b,d,f$ are also positive recurrent. $b,d,f$ all communicate, so it would suffice to show that one of these are positive recurrent. To show positive recurrent, I need to show:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}P^k_{ff}}{n}>0$$
I am having trouble finding a closed expression for $P^k_{ff}$ as there seems to be many ways to calculate this probability, especially as $k$ grows bigger. For example, for $P^5_{ff}$, we could have the pattern $f,b,b,b,d,f$ or $f,b,d,b,d,f$ and this seems to only get more complicated for larger $k$ since we can do various repetitions of revisiting $b$ or $d$. Is there an easier way to prove positive recurrence that bypasses the combinatorics problem of calculating the myriad of ways to return to $f$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084415 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297278. You can apply these observations by inspecting the graph of your transition matrix to identify the recurrent states.

Comment: These make sense but I suppose I am having difficulty on the formality of the answer. Could I make an argument like the following: look at a "sub markov chain" with $S = \{b,d,f\}$, then this DTMC is irreducible and has finite state space => we have a unique stationary distribution => each state in this sub chain is pos recurr